# How can i use burst camera mode of new android phones in my app?

Tags: android, android-camera

It seems a lot of new android phones have this burst mode feature for their camera and they use it in their native camera apps. I was wondering if there is an api that they use in their apps or maybe they are just taking photos in a loop, i couldn't be sure, so can anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official API for it, but before you go ahead and start looping .takePicture(), you should probably be calling it again on a [picture callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html) to avoid  taking up the entire CPU if there's a delay in taking a picture for any reason :)

Comment: So do you think it would be as fast as native galaxy s3 camera app's burst mode?

Comment: Honestly no idea, the best thing to do would be to give it a try, if not maybe go with the looping but be careful not to make the app crash on not as good phones, maybe delay each call to give chance to catch up :)