# Error in taking multiple picture in one second on Android

Tags: java, android, camera

I want to use the Android to take multiple images in one second. The basic idea is to use a Timer at a certain FPS that will trigger the camera to capture images.

The problem is that when I want to trigger the camera more than 1 times in one second, say every 500ms, there will be an error in startPreview.  `java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed`

How can i fixed this?. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149168/burst-mode-camera-in-android-which-can-take-multiple-pictures/23221414#23221414

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. I tested that the time to `startPreview()` and `takePicture()` varies from 1ms to at most 50ms. You said that we cannot know the safe timestep between 2 `takePicture()`. Have you test if there is a safe timestep between 2 `startPreview()`? My error here is 'startPreview failed'.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `startPreview()` in your `onPictureTaken()` callback, and nothing guarantees that this callback will be activated at the frame rate you expected. Many cameras provide burst-shot mode, but there is no common API yet. Hopefully, soon this API [will arrive](http://www.phonedog.com/2013/11/25/google-confirms-android-camera-api-with-raw-and-burst-mode-support-teases-nexus-5-update/).

Answer (score 0):

I take the same error for trying to take many pictures even when the camera is not ready.
So you should define a boolean isItSafeToTakePicture to control if the previous photo-take-action is finished.

Using a boolean like this should solve the issue, even though you may not be able to set 500 ms interval for taking photos, this boolean will define the minimum time limit.